# AngularJs data-ng-option unsort my data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my web page i'have this select input:

```
<select class="form-control" 
  data-ng-model="rigav.idLocalita" 
  data-ng-options="luogo.id as luogo[rigav.tipoLocalita.toLowerCase()]+' ' + luogo['cap'] for (indice, luogo) in $eval(rigav.tipoLocalita)"
  data-ng-disabled="!rigav.nuova"
  data-ng-change="rigav.localita=cambiaLocalita(rigav, $eval(rigav.tipoLocalita))"
   >
</select>
```

The options are recived from a web service and they are sorted at origin (they are a list of cities sorted by name), but in the component the values are re-ordered in some way ???

Why are the values re-ordered ? 
How can I show the entries in the same order I recived them?

Adding an **orderBy** option to data-ng-options do nothing

Answer (score 0):

In data-ng-options you defined some sorting order. You should remove that sorting order and you will get what service sent you.

Comment: I have edited the question. The real code is without orderBy

Comment: You could try to sort them right after you get them from server. For example on success clause of your get request. But i really don't know why orderBy in ng-repeat doesn't work for you.